# How to set margins for Layout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I declared a linearlayout with horizontal orientation programatically. 
How to set width,height,margins for that layout dynamically. 
I tried like the below :

```
         leftMargin = 40;
         rightMargin = 20;
         widgetWidth = 300;
         topMargin = 5;
         bottomMargin = 5;
         widgetHeight = 100;
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams((int) widgetWidth, (int) widgetHeight);
        params.setMargins((int) leftMargin, (int) topMargin,
                (int) rightMargin, (int) bottomMargin);
        newHorizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
        newHorizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        newHorizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But I'm getting null pointer exception.
can anyone help me in sorting out his issue.

Comment: in which line? Where is the stacktrace? *if I would get a penny for every "where is the stack trace" sentence...*

Comment: please provide your logcat

Comment: maybe ctx is null? Which LayoutParams did you imported?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to import correct layout. Here is a example of table-row layoutParams:

To set height and width:

```
TextView tb_row_proName;
android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams lp_pro_name = new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);         
tb_row_proName.setLayoutParams(lp_pro_name);
```

To set margin:

```
int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, r.getDisplayMetrics());
lp_pro_name.bottomMargin = margin;
```

Comment: http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm - Variables: Names should be in mixed case.